# set matrix zreos :free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00000000029c21d0

Tags: c++

problem : Set matrix zeroes (A practice in leetcode https://leetcode.com/problems/set-matrix-zeroes/submissions/)
Given a m x n matrix, if an element is 0, set its entire row and column to 0. Do it in-place.

```
Example 1:

Input: 
[
  [1,1,1],
  [1,0,1],
  [1,1,1]
]
Output: 
[
  [1,0,1],
  [0,0,0],
  [1,0,1]
]
Example 2:

Input: 
[
  [0,1,2,0],
  [3,4,5,2],
  [1,3,1,5]
]
Output: 
[
  [0,0,0,0],
  [0,4,5,0],
  [0,3,1,0]
]
Follow up:

A straight forward solution using O(mn) space is probably a bad idea.
A simple improvement uses O(m + n) space, but still not the best solution.
Could you devise a constant space solution?
```

when I submit my code ,there is a **error** :
[image]

I want to know why it is wrong ?
this is my code :

```
class Solution {
public:
    void setZeroes(vector<vector<int>>& matrix) {
        int i,j;
        int col_size = matrix[0].size();
        int *flag = new int [col_size + 1];
        for(i = 0; i < matrix.size();i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < matrix[i].size(); j++)
            {
                if(matrix[i][j] == 0)
                {
                    flag[i] = 1;
                    flag[col_size] = 1;
                }

            }
            if(flag[col_size] == 1)
            {
                for(j = 0; j < matrix[i].size(); j++)
                {
                    matrix[i][j] = 0;
                } 
                flag[col_size] = 0;
            }
        }
        for(j = 0; j < col_size; j++)
        {
            if(flag[j] == 1)
                for(i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++)
                {
                    matrix[i][j] = 0;
                }
        }
        delete [] flag;
    }
};
```

Thank you!

Comment: you're using `vector` and you still use `new` to create arrays? that's really weird. Just don't use `new`. And it's C++ not C

Comment: That an error you typically get when writing out of bounds. A possible hint: What happens if `matrix.size() > col_size`?

Comment: A lot of times in these submitted code challenges, the difficulty is that you don't get the input that crashed it (or what kind of crash it was).  But you apparently have the input--which makes it substantially easier to figure out what's wrong.  What debugger are you using when you compile it yourself?  If you are not using a debugger, you should be.

Comment: check dimensions of your matrices: i goes to `matrix.size()`, flag is allocated with `matrix[0].size()`

Comment: use a `vector` for `flag` and access with `at`. No need to free, if an index goes out of bounds you get a clear exception

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry! I didn't check my codes seriously.The bug is `flag[i] = 1` should be `flag[j] = 1`
[image]

Now,the codes are able to run.
[image]

Thank you for your kind answer!

Comment: This is not an answer. It could be a comment to the helpful answer, plus an addition (via editing) to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have allocated flag of size matrix[0].size() i.e. number of columns.
But here -

```
    flag[i] = 1;
```

i goes to matrix.size()-1  i.e. number of rows.
For M x N matrix, if M > N (Actually N+1 here, since you have allocated extra location for other purpose), your code is modifying location outside the array.
Here -

```
    delete [] flag;
```

you are deleting more memory than allocated for M > N + 1.

Comment: You are right, I use the extra location（the last location ) to record whether there 
 are zeroes in the current row. Thank you!